# payment processing using authorize.net

Tags: authorize.net

I am using the authorize.net as my payment gateway which accept payment from credit card. I am always getting the error message:

> Transactions of this market type cannot be processed on this system

I am using test account, how can I tackle this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the suggestions detailed on the related [Authorize.net support article](https://support.authorize.net/authkb/index?page=content&id=A597&actp=LIST)?

> This can happen for four reasons:
>
> 1) You are attempting to process a type of transaction that your account is not designed to process. An example would be using a card swipe machine to process transactions on an e-commerce or mail order/telephone order (MOTO) account.
>
> 2) You are passing an incorrect value to the field x_market_type. If you are using a Retail account you want to pass a value of "2". The Implementation Guide for Card Present transactions can be found at http://www.authorize.net/support/CP_guide.pdf.
>
> 3) Your Merchant Service Provider may be incorrectly setup for this account.
>
> 4) The product type (SIC code) is incorrect for this account.