# authorize.net sandbox testing giving error

Tags: php, sandbox, authorize.net

I am integrating authorize.net in PHP. I have used http://developer.authorize.net/integration/fifteenminutes/#custom this sdk for my development.

For testing, I have created an sandbox account. When I am executing the code - I'm getting below error:-

```
AuthorizeNet Error: Response Code: 3 
 Response Subcode: 1 
 Response Reason Code: 87 
 Response Reason Text: (TESTMODE) Transactions of this market type cannot be processed on this system.
```

**How will I recover this issue and will make an successful test?**

I have also checked [payment processing using authorize.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9128559/payment-processing-using-authorize-net). But not helped me so much.

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:- code is below**

```
function authorizeNet($options)
{

    require_once '../anet_php_sdk/AuthorizeNet.php'; // Make sure this path is correct.

    $transaction = new AuthorizeNetAIM('YOUR_API_LOGIN_ID', 'YOUR_TRANSACTION_KEY');
    $transaction->amount = $options["gift_amt"];
    $transaction->card_num = $options["card_no"];
    $transaction->exp_date = $options["card_expiry"];

    $response = $transaction->authorizeAndCapture();

    if ($response->approved) {
      echo "<h1>Success! The test credit card has been charged!</h1>";
      echo "Transaction ID: " . $response->transaction_id;
      die();
    } else {
      echo $response->error_message;
      die();
    }
}
```

in the place of YOUR_API_LOGIN_ID and YOUR_TRANSACTION_KEY - I placed correct information. Here I don't want to disclose so I haven't mentioned it here.

Comment: Please provide your code which you are using.

Comment: @cmorrissey yes providing.

Comment: can you var_dump your $options and post them

Comment: it's only array of amount, card no , and card expiry. I posted it manually.

Comment: well these values may be incorrectly formatted causing your error, with out that information ... its impossible to help further

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that the account that you are using was created for Card Present (retail) transactions, but you are trying to integrate to our Card Not Present (e-commerce) APIs or vice versa. The only way to resolve this is to open a new sandbox account with the correct market type.